# How automatically break line/numbering a text in XeLaTex

Tags: xetex, line-breaking, enumerate

I want to know that if exist a method to automatically break two differents lines. The problem is that I want to put this poem: [Odyssey of Homer] and produce a document that enumerate the lines [after 5 lines, like 5 - 10 - 15 ..., like I put in lines] and break each verse of the poem [without I put manually in each line `\\`, `\newline`, and others... ]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[margin=0.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\setmainlanguage{brazil}
\setotherlanguage[variant=ancient]{greek}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}

\begin{document}
ἄνδρα μοι ἔννεπε, μοῦσα, πολύτροπον, ὃς μάλα πολλὰ
πλάγχθη, ἐπεὶ Τροίης ἱερὸν πτολίεθρον ἔπερσεν:
πολλῶν δ᾽ ἀνθρώπων ἴδεν ἄστεα καὶ νόον ἔγνω,
πολλὰ δ᾽ ὅ γ᾽ ἐν πόντῳ πάθεν ἄλγεα ὃν κατὰ θυμόν,
[5] ἀρνύμενος ἥν τε ψυχὴν καὶ νόστον ἑταίρων.
ἀλλ᾽ οὐδ᾽ ὣς ἑτάρους ἐρρύσατο, ἱέμενός περ:
αὐτῶν γὰρ σφετέρῃσιν ἀτασθαλίῃσιν ὄλοντο,
νήπιοι, οἳ κατὰ βοῦς Ὑπερίονος Ἠελίοιο
ἤσθιον: αὐτὰρ ὁ τοῖσιν ἀφείλετο νόστιμον ἦμαρ.
[10] τῶν ἁμόθεν γε, θεά, θύγατερ Διός, εἰπὲ καὶ ἡμῖν.

ἔνθ᾽ ἄλλοι μὲν πάντες, ὅσοι φύγον αἰπὺν ὄλεθρον,
οἴκοι ἔσαν, πόλεμόν τε πεφευγότες ἠδὲ θάλασσαν:
τὸν δ᾽ οἶον νόστου κεχρημένον ἠδὲ γυναικὸς
νύμφη πότνι᾽ ἔρυκε Καλυψὼ δῖα θεάων
[15] ἐν σπέσσι γλαφυροῖσι, λιλαιομένη πόσιν εἶναι.
ἀλλ᾽ ὅτε δὴ ἔτος ἦλθε περιπλομένων ἐνιαυτῶν,
τῷ οἱ ἐπεκλώσαντο θεοὶ οἶκόνδε νέεσθαι
εἰς Ἰθάκην, οὐδ᾽ ἔνθα πεφυγμένος ἦεν ἀέθλων
καὶ μετὰ οἷσι φίλοισι. θεοὶ δ᾽ ἐλέαιρον ἅπαντες
[20] νόσφι Ποσειδάωνος: ὁ δ᾽ ἀσπερχὲς μενέαινεν
ἀντιθέῳ Ὀδυσῆι πάρος ἣν γαῖαν ἱκέσθαι.

ἀλλ᾽ ὁ μὲν Αἰθίοπας μετεκίαθε τηλόθ᾽ ἐόντας,
Αἰθίοπας τοὶ διχθὰ δεδαίαται, ἔσχατοι ἀνδρῶν,
οἱ μὲν δυσομένου Ὑπερίονος οἱ δ᾽ ἀνιόντος,
[25] ἀντιόων ταύρων τε καὶ ἀρνειῶν ἑκατόμβης.
ἔνθ᾽ ὅ γ᾽ ἐτέρπετο δαιτὶ παρήμενος: οἱ δὲ δὴ ἄλλοι
Ζηνὸς ἐνὶ μεγάροισιν Ὀλυμπίου ἁθρόοι ἦσαν.
τοῖσι δὲ μύθων ἦρχε πατὴρ ἀνδρῶν τε θεῶν τε:
μνήσατο γὰρ κατὰ θυμὸν ἀμύμονος Αἰγίσθοιο,
[30] τόν ῥ᾽ Ἀγαμεμνονίδης τηλεκλυτὸς ἔκταν᾽ Ὀρέστης:
τοῦ ὅ γ᾽ ἐπιμνησθεὶς ἔπε᾽ ἀθανάτοισι μετηύδα:
‘
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in several ways depending on the way you want it to look. Your mwe is a bit confusing here since you specify a very small margin on a book class. The reason why it may be an issue is that usually, line numbers are written in the margin, and with that setting, the margin is too small. Putting that aside...

If you want to not have to write the `\\` at the end of each line, you need to use a verbatim environment, `alltt` is usually used for that where you can change the font back to the default non-monospace one. For the line number you will need to use an additional package, such as, `lineno`. The following code does pretty much what you ask:

```
\documentclass[11pt,preview,margin=1cm]{standalone}
%\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\setmainlanguage{brazil}
\setotherlanguage[variant=ancient]{greek}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}

\usepackage{alltt}
\usepackage{lineno}

\begin{document}
{
\internallinenumbers\modulolinenumbers[5]
\begin{alltt}\normalfont
ἄνδρα μοι ἔννεπε, μοῦσα, πολύτροπον, ὃς μάλα πολλὰ
πλάγχθη, ἐπεὶ Τροίης ἱερὸν πτολίεθρον ἔπερσεν:
πολλῶν δ᾽ ἀνθρώπων ἴδεν ἄστεα καὶ νόον ἔγνω,
πολλὰ δ᾽ ὅ γ᾽ ἐν πόντῳ πάθεν ἄλγεα ὃν κατὰ θυμόν,
ἀρνύμενος ἥν τε ψυχὴν καὶ νόστον ἑταίρων.
ἀλλ᾽ οὐδ᾽ ὣς ἑτάρους ἐρρύσατο, ἱέμενός περ:
αὐτῶν γὰρ σφετέρῃσιν ἀτασθαλίῃσιν ὄλοντο,
νήπιοι, οἳ κατὰ βοῦς Ὑπερίονος Ἠελίοιο
ἤσθιον: αὐτὰρ ὁ τοῖσιν ἀφείλετο νόστιμον ἦμαρ.
τῶν ἁμόθεν γε, θεά, θύγατερ Διός, εἰπὲ καὶ ἡμῖν.

ἔνθ᾽ ἄλλοι μὲν πάντες, ὅσοι φύγον αἰπὺν ὄλεθρον,
οἴκοι ἔσαν, πόλεμόν τε πεφευγότες ἠδὲ θάλασσαν:
τὸν δ᾽ οἶον νόστου κεχρημένον ἠδὲ γυναικὸς
νύμφη πότνι᾽ ἔρυκε Καλυψὼ δῖα θεάων
ἐν σπέσσι γλαφυροῖσι, λιλαιομένη πόσιν εἶναι.
ἀλλ᾽ ὅτε δὴ ἔτος ἦλθε περιπλομένων ἐνιαυτῶν,
τῷ οἱ ἐπεκλώσαντο θεοὶ οἶκόνδε νέεσθαι
εἰς Ἰθάκην, οὐδ᾽ ἔνθα πεφυγμένος ἦεν ἀέθλων
καὶ μετὰ οἷσι φίλοισι. θεοὶ δ᾽ ἐλέαιρον ἅπαντες
νόσφι Ποσειδάωνος: ὁ δ᾽ ἀσπερχὲς μενέαινεν
ἀντιθέῳ Ὀδυσῆι πάρος ἣν γαῖαν ἱκέσθαι.

ἀλλ᾽ ὁ μὲν Αἰθίοπας μετεκίαθε τηλόθ᾽ ἐόντας,
Αἰθίοπας τοὶ διχθὰ δεδαίαται, ἔσχατοι ἀνδρῶν,
οἱ μὲν δυσομένου Ὑπερίονος οἱ δ᾽ ἀνιόντος,
ἀντιόων ταύρων τε καὶ ἀρνειῶν ἑκατόμβης.
ἔνθ᾽ ὅ γ᾽ ἐτέρπετο δαιτὶ παρήμενος: οἱ δὲ δὴ ἄλλοι
Ζηνὸς ἐνὶ μεγάροισιν Ὀλυμπίου ἁθρόοι ἦσαν.
τοῖσι δὲ μύθων ἦρχε πατὴρ ἀνδρῶν τε θεῶν τε:
μνήσατο γὰρ κατὰ θυμὸν ἀμύμονος Αἰγίσθοιο,
τόν ῥ᾽ Ἀγαμεμνονίδης τηλεκλυτὸς ἔκταν᾽ Ὀρέστης:
τοῦ ὅ γ᾽ ἐπιμνησθεὶς ἔπε᾽ ἀθανάτοισι μετηύδα:
‘
\end{alltt}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note however that the line numbers are wrong as it takes into account the blank lines between stanzas. `lineno` doesn't do that in normal text but since we are using a verbatim mode, a blank line is indeed counted as a line in its own right. There is probably a way to fix this but I haven't figured it out yet.

Also with this solution, your text is not indented compared to the rest of the text which is usually the way verses are typeset. You would have to play with another environment such as `varwidth` or `minipage` to do that.

The other thing to be aware of with that solution is that if a line is too long it will not be broken and you will get an `overfull hbox`

---

For verses and poetry, LaTeX provides the `verse` environment which is basic but can be sufficient in most cases. However it require you to terminate each verse with `\\` and doesn't offer the line numbering facility.

For that a package was create that replaces the original `verse` environment with something a lot more configurable. It still requires you to add `\\` at the end of each lines (and `\\!` at the end of each stanza if you are using line numbers) but numbering is possible the way you want it.

```
\documentclass[11pt,preview,margin=1cm]{standalone}
%\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\setmainlanguage{brazil}
\setotherlanguage[variant=ancient]{greek}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}

\usepackage{verse}
\usepackage{alltt}
\usepackage{lineno}

\begin{document}

\poemlines{5}
\verselinenumbersleft
\setlength{\vrightskip}{-4em}
\verselinenumfont{\tiny\raggedright}
\selectlanguage{greek}
\begin{verse}
ἄνδρα μοι ἔννεπε, μοῦσα, πολύτροπον, ὃς μάλα πολλὰ\\
πλάγχθη, ἐπεὶ Τροίης ἱερὸν πτολίεθρον ἔπερσεν:\\
πολλῶν δ᾽ ἀνθρώπων ἴδεν ἄστεα καὶ νόον ἔγνω,\\
πολλὰ δ᾽ ὅ γ᾽ ἐν πόντῳ πάθεν ἄλγεα ὃν κατὰ θυμόν,\\
ἀρνύμενος ἥν τε ψυχὴν καὶ νόστον ἑταίρων.\\
ἀλλ᾽ οὐδ᾽ ὣς ἑτάρους ἐρρύσατο, ἱέμενός περ:\\
αὐτῶν γὰρ σφετέρῃσιν ἀτασθαλίῃσιν ὄλοντο,\\
νήπιοι, οἳ κατὰ βοῦς Ὑπερίονος Ἠελίοιο\\
ἤσθιον: αὐτὰρ ὁ τοῖσιν ἀφείλετο νόστιμον ἦμαρ.\\
τῶν ἁμόθεν γε, θεά, θύγατερ Διός, εἰπὲ καὶ ἡμῖν.\\!

ἔνθ᾽ ἄλλοι μὲν πάντες, ὅσοι φύγον αἰπὺν ὄλεθρον,\\
οἴκοι ἔσαν, πόλεμόν τε πεφευγότες ἠδὲ θάλασσαν:\\
τὸν δ᾽ οἶον νόστου κεχρημένον ἠδὲ γυναικὸς\\
νύμφη πότνι᾽ ἔρυκε Καλυψὼ δῖα θεάων\\
ἐν σπέσσι γλαφυροῖσι, λιλαιομένη πόσιν εἶναι.\\
ἀλλ᾽ ὅτε δὴ ἔτος ἦλθε περιπλομένων ἐνιαυτῶν,\\
τῷ οἱ ἐπεκλώσαντο θεοὶ οἶκόνδε νέεσθαι\\
εἰς Ἰθάκην, οὐδ᾽ ἔνθα πεφυγμένος ἦεν ἀέθλων\\
καὶ μετὰ οἷσι φίλοισι. θεοὶ δ᾽ ἐλέαιρον ἅπαντες\\
νόσφι Ποσειδάωνος: ὁ δ᾽ ἀσπερχὲς μενέαινεν\\
ἀντιθέῳ Ὀδυσῆι πάρος ἣν γαῖαν ἱκέσθαι.\\!

ἀλλ᾽ ὁ μὲν Αἰθίοπας μετεκίαθε τηλόθ᾽ ἐόντας,\\
Αἰθίοπας τοὶ διχθὰ δεδαίαται, ἔσχατοι ἀνδρῶν,\\
οἱ μὲν δυσομένου Ὑπερίονος οἱ δ᾽ ἀνιόντος,\\
ἀντιόων ταύρων τε καὶ ἀρνειῶν ἑκατόμβης.\\
ἔνθ᾽ ὅ γ᾽ ἐτέρπετο δαιτὶ παρήμενος: οἱ δὲ δὴ ἄλλοι\\
Ζηνὸς ἐνὶ μεγάροισιν Ὀλυμπίου ἁθρόοι ἦσαν.\\
τοῖσι δὲ μύθων ἦρχε πατὴρ ἀνδρῶν τε θεῶν τε:\\
μνήσατο γὰρ κατὰ θυμὸν ἀμύμονος Αἰγίσθοιο,\\
τόν ῥ᾽ Ἀγαμεμνονίδης τηλεκλυτὸς ἔκταν᾽ Ὀρέστης:\\
τοῦ ὅ γ᾽ ἐπιμνησθεὶς ἔπε᾽ ἀθανάτοισι μετηύδα:\\!
\end{verse}
\end{document}
```

[image]

To me this is the best way to typeset your text. Granted you have to do a little more work with the end of lines but it should be very easy to automate with a well crafted search&replace regular expression. Have look at the manual for the `verse` package for all the different options it offers.